# Find 'word' not followed by a certain character

Tags: regex

What is the regular expression to search for `word` string that is not followed by the `@` symbol?

For example:

```
mywordLLD         OK
myword.dff        OK
myword@ld         Exclude
```

Comment: `word[^@]`?  It covers all the examples; it doesn't cover a line which ends with `word`; for that, you'd need `word($|[^@])` instead.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You've been here long enough to know to post answers as answers, not as comments. :) Anyway, that also includes the next character in the match, so for instance `s/word[^@]/otherword/g` won't have the same effect as stribizhev's answer of using a lookahead.

Comment: **See Also**: [A regex to match a substring that isn't followed by a certain other substring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2631010/1366033)

Answer (score 211, accepted):

The `(?!@)` negative [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) will make `word` match only if `@` does not appear *immediately after* `word`:

```
word(?!@)
```

If you need to fail a match when a `word` is followed with a character/string *somewhere to the right*, you may use any of the three below

```
word(?!.*@)       # Note this will require @ to be on the same line as word
(?s)word(?!.*@)   # (except Ruby, where you need (?m)): This will check for @ anywhere...
word(?![\s\S]*@)  # ... after word even if it is on the next line(s)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vY3pY3/1)

This regex matches `word` substring and `(?!@)` makes sure there is no `@` right after it, and if it is there, the `word` is not returned as a match (i.e. the match *fails*).

From [Regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

> **Negative lookahead** is indispensable if you want to match something not followed by something else. When explaining [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), **this tutorial explained why you cannot use a negated character class to match a `q` not followed by a `u`. Negative lookahead provides the solution: `q(?!u)`**. The negative lookahead construct is *the pair of parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark and an exclamation point*.

And on [Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) page:

> It is important to remember that a negated character class still must match a character. `q[^u]` does not mean: "a `q` not followed by a `u`". It means: "a `q` followed by a character that is not a `u`". It does not match the `q` in the string `Iraq`. It does match the `q` and the space after the `q` in Iraq is a country. Indeed: the space becomes part of the overall match, because it is the "character that is not a `u`" that is matched by the negated character class in the above regexp. If you want the regex to match the `q`, and only the `q`, in both strings, you need to use **negative lookahead**: `q(?!u)`.

Comment: For R users, be sure to add `perl = TRUE` to your command, like `gsub("word(?!@)", "", obj, perl = TRUE)`. Otherwise it will throw an error 'Invalid regexp'.

Comment: @xwhitelight You are just not looking at the right place, see [Why is this regex using lookbehinds invalid in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420391/why-is-this-regex-using-lookbehinds-invalid-in-r). In POSIX regex flavors, lookaheads are not supported at all, so one can't use `(?!...)` or `(?=...)` in `sed` or `awk`, or with `grep` unless you use `-P` option. RE2 does not support lookaheads either (so, Go, Google Docs/Sheets REGEX* functions are affected). Oracle regex does not support lookaheads either.

Comment: Just curious if I play around with the demos will they return back to their original state when I leave the site?

Comment: Your comment about RE2 was valuable because I just wrote a little thing as a dialog and a webapp and realized when I read your comment that it works because I'm running it client side in javascript.

Comment: Just another tip: `word(?![\s\S]*@)` is not optimal if all you want is to find `word` before a `@` in a string, you should consider using `word(?![^@]*@)`. However, `[\s\S]*` or `[\s\S]*?` is more generic, and simpler if you want to match before a multiple character substring.