# Replace (LaTeX) commands by html entities in string with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, command, latex

I have a dictionary for LaTeX commands/html entities:

```
var translations = [
    {tex: '\\latex', html: 'LaTeX'},
    {tex: '\\cup', html: '∪'},
    {tex: '\\cap', html: '∩'},
    {tex: '\\ldots', html: '…'},
    {tex: '\\leftarrow', html: '←'},
    {tex: '\\leftrightarrow', html: '↔'}
    ...
];
```

Now I want to replace each LaTeX command by its html entity. I guess the best basic structure is like this:

```
function translateFromTexToHTML(string) {
    for (i = 0; i < translations.length; i += 1) {
        re = new RegExp('...\\' + translations[i].tex + '...');
        string = string.replace(re, '...' + translations[i].html);
    }
    return string;
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out which regular expression I need. I tried this:

```
var re = new RegExp('\\' + translations[k].tex + '([^a-zA-Z])', 'g');
string .replace(re, translations[k].html + '$1');
```

This partly works, for example,

```
\leftarrow \leftrightarrow becomes ← ↔
```

But, for example,

```
\leftarrow\leftrightarrow becomes ←\leftrightarrow instead ←↔
```

I guess it is because the backslash of the second `\cup` becomes part of the replacement of the first and hence is not matched anymore.

Also is the basic structure efficient?

Help much appreciated.

Comment: I have checked the last regex, and it seems you just consume the letter after the *tex*. Put it into a lookahead: `\\leftarrow(?=[^a-zA-Z])`. Or, just use a word boundary `\\leftarrow\b` (which means *match `w` before a non-word (not `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` character*). That is, `var re = RegExp('\\' + Tools.SVG.translations[k].tex + '\\b', 'g');`.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it does not work for commands at the end of the string. (LaTeX actually accepts `\leftarrow7` as the command `\leftarrow` followed by the (non-command) number `7`. So the word boundary does not work. But the lookahead does.)

Comment: Just as a note: I also wanted to remove an optional space at the end of the command, so it becomes possible to have `A\leftarrow B` come out with minimal space as `A←B`: `(\\s|(?![a-zA-Z]))`

Comment: You can even use a non-capturing group then: `(?:\\s|(?![a-zA-Z]))` (to keep regex capture buffer clean).

Comment: Thanks. Though I am not sure what it means to 'keep regex capture buffer clean'...

Comment: When you specify a capturing group, the regex engine keeps the submatch text inside its buffer. It slows down the regex performance just a tiny bit, so if you need parentheses just for grouping, it is best practice to use a non-capturing group.

Comment: @Daniel would you mind sharing your LaTeX commands/html entities dictionary with me? I'm looking for exactly this! Thanks :)

Comment: @MauritsMoeys Sorry, I had only a very short dictionary implemented and did not continue with it since I went for MathJax instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the last subpattern in your regex is a negated character class that actually *consumes* input leaving no chance of matching the next entity during the next iteration.

Just place it inside a negative lookahead with a non-negated character class:

```
\\leftarrow(?![a-zA-Z])
```

or

```
var re = RegExp('\\' + translations[k].tex + '(?![a-zA-Z])', 'g');
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tE3sE2/1)

See more on [how negative lookahead works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201690/find-word-not-followed-by/31201710#31201710) (and in general, lookarounds).

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the variable names by copy and paste (`Tools.SVG.translations = translations`). I added an end of string character `$` to the lookahead to also match end of string: `(?=[^a-zA-Z]|$)`. Is that correct?

Comment: Use the negative lookahead with a positive character class, you won't need to specify the end of string alternative that way I added a regex demo.