# How to match regex for any two numbers not both zero?

Tags: regex

**Examples**:

```
01  =  match
10  =  match
99  =  match
00  =  no match
```

---

So far I have this: `/^ [1-9][0-9] | [0-9][1-9] $/` but I have the feeling it can be optimized.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use a negative lookahead to restrict a generic `[0-9]{2}` pattern:

```
^(?!00)[0-9]{2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cM4jH4/1)

The `[0-9]{2}` will match exactly 2 digits. The `(?!00)` [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) will be executed once at the beginning of the string and will make sure there are no `00` until the string end. If the string equals to `00`, no match will be found.

See more at [How Negative Lookahead Works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201690/find-word-not-followed-by/31201710#31201710).

A detailed pattern explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!00)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are two `0`s right after the current position (at the beginning of the string). Since the next subpattern - `[0-9]{2}$` - only allows 2 symbols in the string, we do not have to add any anchor into the lookahead, in other scenarios, it is a must to add `$` to just exclude `00` match.
- `[0-9]{2}` - exactly two (thanks to the limiting quantifier `{min(,max)?}`) digits (in most flavors, `[0-9]` can be replaced with `\d`, but that `\d` can also match more than regular `[0123456789]` in some of the flavors)
- `$` - end of string (depending on the regex flavor, `\z` can be preferable as it matches the *very end* of string).

Answer (score 2):

Try this RegEx:

```
(?!00)\d\d
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/uK5uD6/1)</kbd>

This uses a [**Negative Lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (here is a [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1749956/5620297) explaining it), `(?! )`. This means is whatever is inside exists, do not match. In this case, it will detect if there are `00`, and fail if there are. If not, select 2 digits (`\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]`)

---

A safer version:

```
^(?!00)\d\d$
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/pJ7rN7/1)</kbd>

This also uses `^`, which states that the data must be at the start of the string (or line with the `m` flag), and `$` the data must be at the end. Therefore when you use `^ $`, the data inside must match the full line / string

---

Here are some examples of Negative Lookahead:

```
# Using the RegEx (?!9)\d
1    # Match
2    # Match
5    # Match
9    # NO MATCH

# Using the RegEx (?!Tom)\w+
Tim    # Match
Joe    # Match
Bob    # Match
Tom    # NO MATCH

# Using the RegEx (?!Foo)\w+(?!Bar)
BarBazFoo    # Match
BazBarFoo    # Mtach
FooBarBaz    # NO MATCH
BazFooBar    # NO MATCH
```

Comment: `(?!00)\d\d` will also match `99` in `9900`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I thought there would only be  2 digits, especially since you used `{2}` in your answer. If there are, then `9900` will never exist. But thanks for informing me!

Comment: A limiting quantifier does not  indicate how many characters there should be in the input, but how many the previous subpattern can match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am aware of that, but your RegEx will only match if there are 2 digits. I concluded that because of the `{2}`

Comment: It will match only 2 digit strings/lines because I deduced that from the original pattern :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That was basically what I concluded. Just wh yin your first comment did you mention that it will match `99` in `9900`, since `9900` will never exist, so it is not relevant