# Regex that allows a single whitespace in the middle but with character limit.

Tags: javascript, regex

Excuse my ignorance but I really need help with this, I need this regex: `[A-Za-z0-9]+\s?[A-Za-z0-9]+` (an username that allows a single whitespace in the middle, but not at the beginning or at the end.), but limiting the **total amount of characters** to minimum 3 and maximun 30.

I have tried to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38713373) using negative lookaheads, but so far is not working.

It has to be a regex, it can't use jQuery or anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use  a positive lookahead here:

```
^(?=.{3,30}$)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\s[A-Za-z0-9]+)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kzAkli/1).

Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{3,30}$)` - there can be 3 to 30 chars (other than linebreak, replace the `.` with `[A-Za-z0-9\s]` to be more specific)
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` -  1+ alphanumeric chars
- `(?:\s[A-Za-z0-9]+)?` - an optional (1 or 0) occurrences of a

  - `\s` - whitespace
  - `[A-Za-z0-9]+` - 1+ alphanumeric symbols
- `$`  - end of string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
(?=^[A-Za-z0-9]+\s?[A-Za-z0-9]+$).{3,30}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/rPUXgT/1). It will match:

```
username123    # this one
user name 123  # this one not (two spaces!)
user name123   # this one
u sername123   # this one
 username123   # this one not (space in the beginning!)
```