# Can you have overlapping characters in Regex?

Tags: regex

Okay a bit of a weird one. I know you can do things a bit different and get what you want, but I am just curious whether the functionality exists somewhere or somehow in a single regex line.

Here is a sample expression:

```
(?s)^\\sqrt[^A-Za-z].*?(\{\\rho\})
              ^          ^
              1          2
```

Character 1 `[^A-Za-z]` is checking for a delimiter.

Character 2 `\{` might be that delimiter. It also might be a space, or a ton of other random characters.

However, even if the delimiter is a space, `\{` must exist, which means `[ {]` is not ideal.

Is it possible to just confirm that the spot filled by character 1 is not a letter, however not have it count as a character? The logic sort of being like;

```
if ("(?s)^\\sqrt[^A-Za-z]" matches) {
    Proceed to evaluate as "(?s)^\\sqrt.*?(\{\\rho\})"
}
```

Comment: I think you need a negative lookahead: `(?s)^\\sqrt(?![A-Za-z]).*?(\{\\rho\})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic you described fits the negative lookahead behavior: it makes sure the text after the current position does not match its pattern.

Use

```
(?s)^\\sqrt(?![A-Za-z]).*?(\{\\rho\})
```

[image]

Here, `^` matches the start of string, then `\\sqrt` matches `\sqrt` and after it, the regex engine asserts that there is no ASCII letter right after it with `(?![A-Za-z])` negative lookahead. Then, `.*?(\{\\rho\})` goes on to match the rest.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Jd4Cy/1).

Also, for more details, see another SO thread describing [negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31201710/3832970) behavior.

Comment: Works. Now I just need to wait 7 minutes to accept. Oh gosh, that makes things so damn easier.