# Regex: I want to match only words without a dot at the end

Tags: javascript, regex

For example: George R.R. Martin
I want to match only George and Martin.

I have tried: `\w+\b.` But doesn't work!

Comment: How did you try that regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My problem is, I dont' know how to negate in regex. How to tell regex that I don't want a dot at the end? The end of the word is `\b`... but what else?

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\w+\b.` matches 1+ word chars that are followed with a word  boundary, and then any char that is a non-word char (as `\b` restricts the following `.` subpattern). Note that this way is not negating anything and you miss an important thing: a literal dot in the regex pattern must be escaped.

You may use a negative lookahead `(?!\.)`:

```js
var s = "George R.R. Martin";
console.log(s.match(/\b\w+\b(?!\.)/g));
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pz1ghB/1)

**Details**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `\b` - trailing word boundary
- `(?!\.)` - there must be no `.` after the last word char matched.

See more about [how negative lookahead works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201690/find-word-not-followed-by/31201710#31201710) here.

Comment: That's all I need. Thank you, so much! I will mark that answer as the best in few mins.