# Global regex with multiple matches, where the separator should be shared in several matches

Tags: regex

First of all, sorry for the unclear title, it's hard to describe (and to find an existing solution for the same reason).

I use this regex in Javascript, to collect numbers in a string :

```
/(?:^|[^\d])([\d]+)(?:$|[^\d])/g
```

Executing it on `"5358..2145"` returns 2 matches, where the submatches are `"5358"` and `"2145"`

But if I use it on `"5358.2145"`, I receive only 1 match : `"5358"`

So, I understand it so :

- The first match is found (`"5358."`) so the point goes in the first match
- What I want as second match is not preceded with start of string or the point because this point already belongs to the first match

How can I change my pattern to find all numbers separated with 1 non-number character ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead at the end:

```
/(?:^|\D)(\d+)(?!\d)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j8f7s5/1)

The pattern matches:

- `(?:^|\D)` - either start of string (`^`) or any non-digit char (`\D`)
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `(?!\d)` - the negative lookahead failing the match if there is a digit immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: You can see [another answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201690/find-word-not-followed-by/31201710#31201710) to see how negative lookaheads work.