# Increase 1 space after period (dot) to 2 but not more in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I am working on a simple text file in vim where I want to end every sentence with 2 spaces after full stop (dot/period).  However, I do not want those sentences which already have 2 spaces after full stop to have further increase in spaces.  The test text could be:

```
This sentence has only 1 space after it. This one has two.  This line has again 1 space only. This is last line.
```

I tried:

```
%s/\. /\.  /g
```

but this increases all spaces by one.  I tried following also but it does not work:

```
%s/\.  \\([^ ]\\)/.  \\1/g
```

How can I achieve this in vim?

Comment: Try `%s/\. \( \)\@!/.  /g` (with 2 spaces in the replacement)

Comment: It does not work. Did u try it?

Comment: The `\( \)\@!` is a construct that fails a match if the pattern inside brackets appears in the string at the given location.

Comment: If it's at the end of each line you have to specify the end with $  like `%s/\. $/\.  /g`

Comment: My text is in form of paragraphs with many sentences. In computer language each paragraph will be called a line. But I want to separate "sentences" by a dot and 2 spaces. Like all sentences in this comment are separated by dot and one space only.

Comment: OK. Your answer works - only that the replacement should be `/.__/` and not `/._/` (each _ indicates a space) as you have mentioned in your comment. Put this as an answer and I will accept it. The stackoverflow system is reducing 2 spaces to one.

Comment: That is why I wrote "(with 2 spaces in the replacement)". It is not the only problem with the SO comments, it also inserts rubbish into comment texts when using too long `code lines`.

Comment: Other answers have also appeared and `%s/\. \+/.  /g` by @JimU is really easiest to understand. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
%s/\. \( \)\@!/.  /g
```

The `\. \( \)\@!` pattern matches a `.` and a space that is not followed with another space.

The `(...)@!` is a *negative lookahead construct* in Vim. See [**Lookbehind / Lookahead Regex in Vim**](https://www.inputoutput.io/lookbehind-lookahead-regex-in-vim/). In other common regex flavors, it is written as `(?!pattern)`. You may learn more about how negative lookaheads work in [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201690/find-word-not-followed-by/31201710#31201710).

To match any whitespace, replace the literal space with `\s` inside the pattern.

Comment: What does @ do here? What is it for?

Comment: @mso: `(...)@!` is a negative lookahead construct in Vim. See [Lookbehind / Lookahead Regex in Vim](https://www.inputoutput.io/lookbehind-lookahead-regex-in-vim/). What in other, NFA, regex flavors is written as `(?!...)`.

Answer (score 7):

**Replaces all periods followed by spaces with a period followed by 2 spaces**

```
%s/\. \+/.  /g
```

Comment: this is the simplest, thus most elegant solution. A win in vim-golf ☺

Comment: However, the engine has to process each `.`+space (even those with just 2 spaces) with this approach. It will also shrink `.` + 3 or more spaces, and nothing is said about that in the question. When using a "lookaround", onyl relevant matches are actually replaced.

Comment: Yes, I think I do not want to reduce multiple spaces if I have intentionally put them there.

Answer (score 3):

well, you shouldn't double the escapes, and it works:

```
:%s/\. \([^ ]\)/.  \1/g
```

result:

```
This sentence has only 1 space after it.  This one has two.  This line has again 1 space only.  This is last line.~
```

Comment: It will be useful if you can explain here how it is working.

Comment: well, it's exactly the regex you wrote, except that your code was matching literally `. \(X\)` (because of the `\\`) instead of `. X` where `X` is anything but a space (and substitued as \1 in the RHS).

Answer (score 1):

**Adds an extra space after periods followed by exactly one space**

```
:%s/\. \zs\ze[^ ]/ /g
```

Comment: `:help \zs` for more info on setting the start and end of a match

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility:

```
:%s/\.  \?/.  /g
```

The `\?` will capture a space (and only one) if it can, effectively not changing anything if there are already two spaces.