# Split string by comma unless followed by a space or a '+'

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I'm trying to split an extremely long string by commas. I have two requirements, however:

1. the comma cannot be followed by a space
2. the comma cannot be followed by a '+' symbol

so for example, the input would be:

```
text = "hello,+how are you?,I am fine, thanks"
```

and the output of this is:

```
['hello,+how are you?', 'I am fine, thanks']
```

i.e. the only comma that seperated the values was the one that was not followed by a '+' or a space

I have managed requirement 1) as follows:

```
re.split(r',(?=[^\s]+)',text)
```

I cannot figure out how to add requirement 2)

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201690/find-word-not-followed-by-a-certain-character/31201710#31201710

Comment: @mk no need to escape anything:  `re.split(r',(?=[^\s+])',text)` == `['hello,+how are you?', 'I am fine, thanks']`

Comment: `re.split(r',(?![+ ])', text)` <-- Negative lookahead. Matches anything containing `,` unless there is a `+` character or a space afterwards.

Comment: @Anthony, doesn't work, result is: `['hello,+how are you?', ' am fine, thanks']`

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to only look for the pattern that you don't want, and exclude it altogether. You do that using negative-lookahead in regular-expression.

```
>>> text = "hello,+how are you?,I am fine, thanks"
>>> re.split(r',(?![+ ])', text)
['hello,+how are you?', 'I am fine, thanks']
```

This will match `,` unless it's followed either by a literal `+` or a `space`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
re.split(r',(?=[^\s +])',text)
```

Comment: Why the space between `\s` and `+`?

Comment: i think space is like or here. its giving this output ['hello,+how are you?', 'I am fine, thanks'], isn't that correct?

Comment: (\s +), i am saying this means, (whitespace or plus-sign), '\s'=whitespace, ' '=or, '+'=plus-sign

Comment: `' '` does not mean "or". All characters inside `[ ]` are already "or"ed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go with @HampusLarsson's answer, but I'd like to squeeze in an answer that doesn't use imported modules:

```
s = "hello,+how are you?,I am fine, thanks"

ind = [0]+[i for i,v in enumerate(s)
           if v == ',' and s[i+1] not in [' ','+']]

parts = [s[i:j].lstrip(',')
         for i,j in zip(ind, ind[1:]+[None])]

print(parts)
```

Output:

```
['hello,+how are you?', 'I am fine, thanks']
```