# How to not conflict with filename when combining grep commands?

Tags: grep

Imagine you want to grep recursively for `string1` but not `string1_suffix`. Trivial approach would be

```
grep -r string1 | grep -v string1_suffix`
```

But what if the file names can contain `string1_suffix`?

A line containing `string1_suffix_data.json: blabla string1` would be filtered away by the second grep.

Is it possible to circumvent this somehow? Of course in this trivial example I could just turn around the first and the second part, but what about the general case?

Comment: Use `grep -P 'string1(?!_suffix)'` with GNU `grep`. See [Find 'word' not followed by a certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201690/find-word-not-followed-by-a-certain-character).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have PCRE with `-P` option, you can use `string1(?!_suffix)`

For a general case, use `^(?!.*str2).*str1` to match lines containing `str1` but not `str2`

With `find+awk` (tested on `GNU awk`, not sure about other implementations)

```
find -type f -exec awk '/str1/ && !/str2/{print FILENAME ":" $0}' {} +
```